# File read access for application but not remote user

Tags: permissions, sudo, remote

**EDIT:** It has been several days without answer or even comment; am I doing something wrong in the question?

---

It looks like I need to troubleshoot our application running at a client's facility. It requires read access of their files, but due to data sensitivity they do not want *me* to have read/write access.

This is probably a very common scenario, but I've not found a solution via google or searching through this forum. Are there suggestions?

For instance, I'm wondering if they can create a sudo entry for me to execute the application as a user with read permission on those files? Perhaps with all that on a sandboxed system... Thanks!

Comment: This is sort of a broad question, so it's difficult to know how to give any sort of specific answer.  If they can create a sudo entry, why not just create an non-privileged account with read-only access?  What kind of data sensitivity is it?  Are they worried about releasing names and other details, so read access would not work any better than read/write?  If they were to sandbox, where would the data come from, and does trying to provide it create just as many issues?  The only thing write access is going to protect is adding/modifying, not seeing.

Comment: The data is sensitive/proprietary, so they don't want me to be able to READ it. Our app is crashing and we are unable to replicate, so I was trying to brainstorm a way to gdb our app on their server using their real data, so the app crashes, but not have a way I can actually read the data myself. Would be happy to revise my question more precisely; thanks for suggestions!

Comment: If they can replicate the issue consistently, have them run an strace against the pid or the process doing the reading/writing.  It may give you some idea what's going on when the app crashes.  If it's inconsistent, have an strace running whenever the app is.  It will require someone with appropriate access to the system to assist, obviously, but it may help.  We recently used this on an issue.  Also, if there's network communications, use tcpdump as well, limited to the ports/protocol you're concerned with.